# keep focus on windows like microsoft windows file explorer

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, gnome-terminal, window

The procedure I describe is useless but it helps me explain the situation.

If I am using terminal, I use it on top of nautilus.

In terminal, I type "cat" then space, then with the mouse I go to nautilus and want to drag and drop a txt file over the terminal, so its path gets printed in terminal.
Pressing 'Enter' then I can see the file content.

The problem is that the terminal window get minimized and I cannot do the procedure without setting the terminal window "Always on top".

I recently used MS Windows, and the file manager keeps all the windows open and adapts their z-index, which may be annoying if you have a lot of windows open, but that very same procedure can be carried out, while on Ubuntu 20.04 I cannot do it.

Comment: How does the terminal window get minimized? A window normally does not minimize by itself. Also in Ubuntu, you can drag a file to the terminal to have the path inserted, but you must make sure you see a little of the terminal as the target to drag.

Comment: I think the op wants to mention the feature where in Windows (file) explorer, when the target window is in focus, you can drag and drop a file from (file) explorer to the target window without the explorer overlapping the target window during the drag and drop.

Comment: Post decidedly unclear: there is reference to automatic "minimizing". So in WIndows, when you click and hold a visible file in the file manager, that window will not come in the front? This is not the case in Linux. This scenario actually is not well covered in Gnome Shell: the "official" way is to drag to the activities button, then in the overview to the target window, but for that to work, the hotcorner must be active. It is not in Ubuntu.